# How to read contacts with a group name using Phonegap on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Just wanna read contacts from mobile's phonebook using Phonegap , is there a way ?

If phonegap provides any filter to do this ?

Any native implementation explanation will also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

PhoneGap Provide access to the device contacts database using `Contacts API` . Please check out here-

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts

http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.phonegap/21918

I hope, it will solve your problem.
Thanks

Comment: I want to access contacts by group name , there is no word called group in whole of that page

Comment: Not resolved ..The other link suggests that you need to have a field in your contacts which refers as group name.
When I checked my contact , it doesnt have a visible field of group name, rather that contact was programatically added to the addressbook

Comment: and I quote "Correct,  currently there is no support of groups in the PhoneGap contacts api.   Please enter an enhancement request"

Comment: @Ecko123 so finally there is no group support in phone gap.. did you mean this

Comment: @Ecko123 yes it is not the right answer, what about your question bro.. is it right?